# How to get latest news posted on twitter by a website

Tags: r, twitter

I am using R and I need to retrieve the few most recent posts from a Twitter user (@ExpressNewsPK) using twitteR api. I have created an account and have an access token, etc. I have used the following command to extract the tweets:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumerkey,consumersecret,accesstoken,accesssecret)
express_news_tweets <- searchTwitter("@ExpressNewsPK", n = 10, lang = "en" )
```

However, the posts that are returned aren't the most recent ones from this user. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You mentioned 'not getting current news', it's a different problem that arises with the use of Twitter Search API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `searchTwitter` would search with the search string provided (here @ExpressNewsPK). So instead of giving tweets by @ExpressNewsPK it would give tweets which are directed to @ExpressNewsPK.

To get tweets from @ExpressNewsPK, you have a function named `userTimeline` which would give tweets from a particular user.

So after you are done with `setup_twitter_oauth`, you can try

```
userTimeline("ExpressNewsPK")
```

read more about it at `?userTimeline`

Comment: I think OP requires current news, using Search API would mostly return a sampled history of tweets.

Comment: Thanks Brother for help

Answer (score 0):

When you use `searchTwitter()`, you call the `Twitter Search API`. Search API only returns a sample history of the tweets.

What you really need to do is to call `Twitter Streaming API`. Using it you'll be able to download tweets in near real time. You can read more about the Streaming API here: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview